# Using regex in snakemake wildcards

Tags: snakemake

I'm using regex in snakemake wildcards but I've come accross an error that I don't understand.

In this shortened example it works:

```
rule graphviz:
    input: "{graph}.dot"
    output: "{graph}.{ext,(pdf|png)}"
    shell: "dot -T{wildcards.ext} -o {output} {input}"
```

In this example, it doesn't:

```
## This is working
rule fastqc:
    input: "{reads}.fastq"
    output: "{reads}_fastqc/{sample}_fastqc.html"
    shell:"fastqc --format fastq {input}"

## This is not working
rule fastqc:
    input: "{reads}.{ext,(bam|fastq)}"
    output: "{reads}_fastqc/{sample}_fastqc.html"
    shell:"fastqc --format {wildcards.ext} {input}"
```

I'm attaching a screencap of the error message I'm getting. Thanks for your help.

[image: Here is a screencap of the error message.]

Comment: My intuition is that in the second case, snakemake doesn't get enough information from the `output`  of `rule fastqc` to determine what value the wildcard "ext" should take. Note also the yellow warnings "wildcard constraints in inputs are ignored". Could this have to do with your problem?

Comment: Actually I thought it was possible to introduce a wildcard in the inputs, but maybe I'm mistaken here... I need to rethink the problem then.

As for the yellow warnings, I've been having those since a recent update of Snakemake without them preventing my workflows to run.